# Chrome kiosk: can auto updates and Safe Browsing downloads be disabled or blocked?

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk, embedded-linux, auto-updates

I are running Chrome in kiosk mode in custom linux environment, and have IoT devices that run on cellular. I am noticing that Chrome periodically downloads approximately 3MB of data an hour, updating its Safe Browsing data. On startup, regardless of what is already in the Chrome .config folder tree, it will chew up close to 30MB.

I have no use for this, in fact it is a serious concern because it unnecessarily uses cellular data.

I've researched and tried starting the app with various command-line switches such as "--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update", they don't seem to have any affect.

How can I disable the auto-updates and Safe Browser info/data downloads?

Comment: You can disable Chrome updates by installing the appropriate group policy Chrome administrator templates.

Comment: Unfortunately we're running a highly customized embedded linux, can't use those. I did manage to get it down to where on boot it only pulls the pnacl plugin / lib, everything else is relatively disabled. Took about 10 different --command-line-switches.

Comment: Why did you fail to provide that information in the question?  It is extremely relevant to your question. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.